# view role titles of the user through assignment table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, devise

Hey I hope you can help me here.

I got a Role model:

`has_many :users, :through => :role_assignments

has_many :role_assignments`

a role assignment model:
`belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :role`

and a user model:
`has_many :roles, :through => :role_assignments

  has_many :role_assignments`

I want to display the users roles in a view.
I tried some stuff like: `user.roles.names` but it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since user.roles is an collection (array) of roles, you can't call names directly. Now I assume that the attribute you want to access is name so in that case you could do:

```
user.roles.map(&:name).join(", ")
```

which will collect all the names from the roles and then join them into a string seperated by commas. That is very simple and not very flexible. If you instead want to style it in some way you could do like this:

```
<% user.roles.each do |role| %>
  <p>Role: <%= role.name %></p>
<% end %>
```